# BeanUtils.copyProperties produces java.lang.VerifyError:

Tags: java, javabeans, apache-commons-beanutils

I am trying to simply copy all properties of one class to another as below. What could be the source of this error?

I have two simple Pojos with different class names but same properties, and copying one from the other after instantiating both

#### Ouput

```
12-25 04:24:33.380  23062-23062/com.example.somghosh.earthmiles I/System.out﹕ *** Before BeanUtils.copyProperties ***
12-25 04:24:33.380  23062-23062/com.example.somghosh.earthmiles I/System.out﹕ Person
12-25 04:24:33.380  23062-23062/com.example.somghosh.earthmiles I/System.out﹕ 15
12-25 04:24:33.380  23062-23062/com.example.somghosh.earthmiles I/System.out﹕ rene
12-25 04:24:33.380  23062-23062/com.example.somghosh.earthmiles I/System.out﹕ othePerson
12-25 04:24:33.380  23062-23062/com.example.somghosh.earthmiles I/System.out﹕ 100
The actual copy code produces error : 

 Process: com.example.somghosh.earthmiles, PID: 23479
    java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtilsBean
            at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.<init>(BeanUtilsBean.java:112)
            at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean$1.initialValue(BeanUtilsBean.java:63)
            at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean$1.initialValue(BeanUtilsBean.java:59)
            at org.apache.commons.beanutils.ContextClassLoaderLocal.get(ContextClassLoaderLocal.java:154)
            at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.getInstance(BeanUtilsBean.java:75)
            at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.copyProperties(BeanUtils.java:135)
            at com.example.somghosh.earthmiles.views.MainActivity.afterViews(MainActivity.java:99)
            at com.example.somghosh.earthmiles.views.MainActivity_.onViewChanged(MainActivity_.java:87)
            at org.androidannotations.api.view.OnViewChangedNotifier.notifyViewChanged(OnViewChangedNotifier.java:41)
            at com.example.somghosh.earthmiles.views.MainActivity_.setContentView(MainActivity_.java:48)
            at com.example.somghosh.earthmiles.views.MainActivity_.onCreate(MainActivity_.java:38)
```

#### Code

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

Person person = new Person();
person.setAge(15);
person.setName("rene");

OtherPerson othePerson = new OtherPerson();

System.out.println("*** Before BeanUtils.copyProperties ***");

System.out.println("Person");
System.out.println(person.getAge());
System.out.println(person.getName());

System.out.println("othePerson");
System.out.println(othePerson.getAge());
System.out.println(othePerson.getName());

//copy properties from (target, source)
try {
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(othePerson, person);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("\n*** After BeanUtils.copyProperties ***");

System.out.println("Person");
System.out.println(person.getAge());
System.out.println(person.getName());

System.out.println("othePerson");
System.out.println(othePerson.getAge());
System.out.println(othePerson.getName());







class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    Person(){
        name = "Person";
        age = 1;


    }
}


class OtherPerson {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    OtherPerson(){
        name = "OtherPerson";
        age = 100;


    }
}
```

Comment: Check the versions you're compiling with and running against; are they the same? Compiling/running with same versions of Java?

Comment: This concept is new to me - I am using Android Studio, and I would assume version of compilation= version of running. How can I check? thanks

Comment: That sounds like you have a corrupted jar.

Answer (score 0):

add this Apache jar into your build path or class path. BeanUtils will need this jar.

```
org.apache.commons.logging
```